# Magento translate attribute textfield

Tags: magento-1.8, inline-translations

In our webshop we specify the fabric of the clothes.

We have an attribute text field for this.
Apart from this we have 3 languages in our store.

Is there a way i could automatically translate some words?

Example.

In English:
80% **cotton**, 20% **wool**

In German:
80% **Baumwolle**, 20% **Wolle**

I could make a list of the most common used fabrics, with there translations.
This would safe me a lot of time when creating the products.

We have magento 1.8.1CE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this out of the box.

What you can think about, but I don't think implementing this is easy and can bring A LOT of trouble, is to create product eav entries in the database for the different text fields and just have a str_replace in it with the different languages.

I think this is a bad idea, because you can do everything, from translating wrong, over translating stuff inside words up to deleting content.

Answer (score 0):

Basically magento uses `locale` files (`.csv`) to translate most of the labels/words.

You will have to find corresponding `.csv` file and just add words to translate.

This [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/translation_and_internationalization/the_ultimate_guide_to_translating_magento_using_translation_memory_software) elaborates more.

But remember, in order to translate text has to be written in this way:

`$this->__('your text')` or `Mage::helper('module_name')->('your text')` in `phtml` file.

Comment: I know that. I am looking for a way to translate words in a textfield.

Comment: Then there is no other way around to it. Unless you write any custom module or find any available one.